# Error using yahoo - Unable to connect or retrieve data from given URL

Tags: matlab, yahoo, yahoo-finance

I use Matlab's fetch function to retrieve historical data from Yahoo Finance. The way to do this according to the official documentation (explained [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/datafeed/yahoo.fetch.html)) is as follows:

**Connect to Yahoo! Finance.**

```
c = yahoo;
```

**Obtain the security data for IBM with today's date.**

```
d = fetch(c,'IBM',now)
```

This all worked fine so far. Since this morning however I am receiving the following error:

```
Error using yahoo
Unable to connect or retrieve data from given URL.
```

What happened? Is the API down or did I change some settings not knowing about it?

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same issue. I also tried to download data manually from yahoo but it didn't work as well then I suppose it's a yahoo issue.

Comment: Switched to Google for the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a MATLAB workaround for new Yahoo, try [this](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1571158)